# variable in PHP not parsing in SQL but ok in echo

Tags: php

I am trying to make a page for the user to change their password when they want, not had any issues with this until now.

I have set the $Username variable, and call it in the SQL Statement along with $oldpw variable.

When I echo the query, the username is always missing.
if I reverse Password & Username, Username is still missing.
if I echo the variable on its own, it's there.

**Regarding Password Security:**
I realize the passwords are not fully protected, but they don't need to be as this is being run on an internal system, which has all the required encryption to get in to it in the first place.

Below is the code & results from a test account with U: Admin & P: Admin

```
<?php
include('SQLFunctions.php');
include('session.php');
session_start();
$link = f_sqlConnect();
$oldpw = ($_POST['oldpw']);
$newpw = ($_POST['newpw']);

if(!isset( $_POST['oldpw']))
{
    $message = 'Please enter a your old password';
}
elseif (strlen( $_POST['newpw']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['newpw']) < 4)
{
    $message = 'incorrect length for new password';
}
elseif (ctype_alnum($_POST['newpw']) != true)
{
    $message = "New password must be alpha numeric";
}
elseif ($_POST['newpw'] <> $_POST['conpw'])
{
    $message = "Your new passwords do not match";
}
elseif(!empty($_POST)) {
    $UserID = $_POST['q'];
    $oldpwd = filter_var($_POST['oldpwd'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $newpwd = filter_var($_POST['newpwd'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

try {
    $Username = $_SESSION['Username'];
    $oldpw = Sha1($oldpw);
    $newps = Sha1($newpw);

    // check whether username exists and check that $oldpass is correct
    $query = "SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Password='".$oldpw."' AND     Username='".$Username."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if(!$result){

        $message = "<p class='message'>Error: Your username and or password are incorrect.</p>" ;
    }else{

        // Test with mysqli_num_rows()
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $query = "
                    UPDATE 
                        Users 
                    SET 
                        Password = '$newpw'
                        ,Updated_by = '$Username'
                        ,LastUpdated = NOW()
                    WHERE 
                        Username = '$Username'";

          mysqli_query($link, $query) or
                die("Insert failed. " . mysqli_error($link));

          $message = "<p class='message'>Your password has been changed</p>";

          mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        else {
           // Username or password is incorrect
            $message = "<p class='message'>Error: Your username and password do not match.</p>" ;
        } 
    }
} catch(Exception $e) { $message = "Unable to process request";
}
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        SVBX - Update Password
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
    <body>
        <?php include('filestart.php') ?>
        <p><?php echo $message;
             echo "<br>Query: ".$query;
             echo "<br>Username :" .$Username;
             echo "<br>UserID :" .$UserID;?></p>
        <?php include('fileend.php') ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

So when I run this I get the following echos:

```
Error: Your username and password do not match.
Query: SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE 
Password='4e7afebcfbae000b22c7c85e5560f89a2a0280b4' AND Username=''
Username :Admin
UserID :18
```

I just can't see what the issue is, appreciate someone pointing out the obvious for me.

Thank you all.

Comment: What do you get when you print the variables with var_dump() right before executing the query?

Comment: The problem is in `filestart.php`. You include it after you generate `$query` and I bet it changes the value of `$Username`.

Comment: var_dump() It tells me the $Username is NULL, but I have no idea why.  And if it is NULL, why is it echoing correctly at the end?

Comment: Apologies, I see what you mean, filestart IS giving me a false echo.  So the $Username is NULL, but why is the Session not providing the $Username like all other pages I have?

Comment: Add `var_dump($_SESSION);` right after your `include('session.php');` and then try again with it right after your `session_start();`. See if there are differences.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Both say NULL, I just can't see why I am losing the session info?

Answer (score 0):

However there are a session related issue. You've included `session.php` which might contain some session related task. Again you've started session in the next line.

I think `$Username` received null from `$_SESSION`. But before you print the username you've included `filestart.php`. However the variable `$Username` has been initialized inside that file.

Comment: Yes, I agree it's a session related issue.  Let me look at trying to fix the session starts.

Comment: Still can't get it to parse from $_Session, it appears as NULL.

you are right about the false echo from the filestart.php, @axiac pointed that out too.

Comment: `$_SESSION` not `$_Session`.

Comment: Correct, sorry that was just my comment, it is `$_SESSION` in the code.

Comment: Just making sure ;) Accuracy n all that.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get the script to work, but it doesn't resolve the issue of why I am losing the `$_SESSION` Info.

I amended the previous pages form, where I know the session information was working, and sent the username to this page using `$_POST`.

It all worked and the password can be changed.

A work around more than a solution.  Thank you everyone for your efforts to help.